# IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE on Ubuntu 12.04: native file watcher executable is outdated

Tags: 12.04, intellij

When I start IntelliJ I get the message `native file watcher executable is outdated` on the top right corner. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (does not happen on my work laptop, with a more recent distro version). What is this exactly? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Usually this is an indication that the file watchers are unable to function properly.  it should go away if you set bin/fsnotifier64 and bin/fsnotifier as executable

```
chmod +x /path/to/intellij/bin/fsnotifier64
```

Comment: That didn't work. The x permission was already there.

Comment: I uninstalled and manually installed from the archive provided on IntelliJ's website and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the version from Ubuntu Software Center and was having the same problem. From what I understand, the program checks the fsnotifier64 for file size, and if the size doesn't match some hardcoded value, it throws this warning:

```
WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher executable is outdated
```

Which shows that popup that you were seeing. I believe that it is up to date, but because of this: [FS#34703 - [intellij-idea-libs] native file watcher broken due to stripped executable](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/34703), the executable is modified and it incorrectly throws that warning.  The only solution I found was to download intellij directly, and replace the fsnotifier64 from the direct download.

On my system the file was located at:

```
/opt/intellij-idea-ce/bin/fsnotifier64
```